# Why record does not go into rails test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end

    # Create sample User 
    User.create  :name => "TestUser"    
  end
end
```

When run `rake db:create`  and `rake db:migrate` command

In development database it creates sample user but not in test database. I want this user in test database also. any reason?

Also tried `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`.

Comment: Your profile may not have sufficient privileges in test database.

Comment: Try `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`. Are there any error messages?

Comment: Yes I have tried this command `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`, but it just migrate schema does not create sample user in test database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should run the following command `rake db:test:prepare` in order to "prepare" the test database.

Finally, I recommend using the following file `db/seeds.rb` if you wish to add new records in your database.

In the `db/seeds.rb` file:

```
User.create(name: "TestUser")
```

Run:

```
rake db:seed
rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test # for test env
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to test a user why not create a fixture or use rspec for testing something like this? The above code is bad practice. I would do something like this

migration file.

```
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end 
  end
```

Depending on your testing stack I would setup a fixture like so([yml fixture](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html))

```
david:
 name: David Smith
```

You could also use rspec with factory girl which makes testing alot easier in rails.